# JSlider knob isn't updating as video progresses

Tags: java, swing, slider, event-dispatch-thread, vlcj

this is my code for updating jslider

```
    try{
    name=(String) jList1.getSelectedValue();
    CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas1);
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
    mediaPlayer.setAdjustVideo(true);        
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(name+".mp4");
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(jSlider1.getMinimum());
    mediaPlayer.parseMedia();
    time = (int)(mediaPlayer.getMediaMeta().getLength()/1000);
    jSlider2.setMaximum(time);
    while(jSlider2.getValue()<jSlider2.getMaximum())
    {
      jSlider2.setValue((int) this.mediaPlayer.getTime()/1000);
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and for changed state of slider this is the code

```
 private void jSlider2StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt)
 {                                      
 mediaPlayer.setTime((long) this.jSlider2.getValue());
}
```

but it doesn't change position of nob,infact it keeps playing from start again anda again.i think reason is that setTime() function keeps updating to 0 before jslider can take new value.is there any solution??maybe using threads??
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
while(jSlider2.getValue() < jSlider2.getMaximum())
{
  jSlider2.setValue((int) this.mediaPlayer.getTime()/1000);
}
```

You're calling a long-running loop on the Swing **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread or EDT, and this will freeze your GUI preventing all painting. Consider running your background process in a SwingWorker's doInBackground method and then updating the GUI via the SwingWorker's publish/process method pair. Also, if you're going to poll the media player, consider putting in a `Thread.sleep(/* some number */)` inside the polling loop since it doesn't make sense to poll almost continuously.

For more on this, please have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: i will search on background process,and change this,hope it will work.thanks a lot